# Being isomorphic as representations of a group G

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group. What is meant by two finite dimensional vector spaces (over $\mathbb{C}$) $V$ and $W$ being "isomorphic as representations of $G$"? To show that we have such an isomorphism, wouldn't it suffice to just show that $\dim V = \dim W$?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, it doesn't suffice that the representation spaces have equal dimension. What is usually meant by isomorphism of representations, is that there exists an *equivariant* isomorphism between the representation spaces, i.e. one that also preserves the action of $G$. In other words, two representations $\pi: G \to GL(V)$ and $\pi': G \to GL(W)$ are isomorphic if there exists an isomorphism $A: V \to W$ such that $A(\pi(g)v) = \pi'(g) Av$.

Comment: Martin's answer is perfect, but let me just add that, in universal algebra, we would simply say the two representations are equivalent iff the resulting algebras $\langle V, \{\pi(g) : g\in G\}\rangle$ and $\langle W, \{\pi'(g) : g\in G\}\rangle$ are isomorphic (which is exactly what Martin's condition says -- i.e. the map $A$ is an algebra isomorphism).

Comment: @Martin Taking what you said further, suppose $G$ has two generators $x,y$ (say). If we know the two objects (modules or vector spaces) are isomorphic when we only consider the $x$-action (say). Then to show they are isomorphic when considering $x$ and $y$, is it sufficient to just find an isomorphism $A$ such that $A(\pi(y)v)=\pi^\prime(y)Av$? Or does this isomorphism need to work for both $x,y$?