# Schur's lemma in Serre's 'Linear Representations of Finite Groups'

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory

I will do a seminar which deals with Serre's 'Linear Representations of Finite Groups' and I am a beginner in this field. I came across Schur's lemma (chapter 2.2). It states:

> [Let $G$ be a finite group and $V_1$ and $V_2$ two complex vector spaces.] 
>  Let $\rho_1:G \rightarrow \text{GL}(V_1)$ and $\rho_2:G \rightarrow \text{GL}(V_2)$ be two irreducible representations of $G$, and let $F$ be a linear mapping of $V_1$ into $V_2$ such that $\rho_2(s)\circ f = f \circ \rho_1(s)$ for all $s \in G$. Then: 
> (1) If $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are not isomorphic, we have $f=0$. 
> (2) If $V_1=V_2$ and $\rho_1=\rho_2$, $f$ is a homothety (a scalar multiple of the identity).

Now my question deals with statement (1). The premise is that $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are not isomorphic. First off, I think it is quite ambiguous what that means. It could mean that both $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are not isomorphic maps in the sense of an isomorphism between $G$ and GL$(V_1)$, resp. GL$(V_2)$. On the other hand it could mean that $\rho_1$ is not isomorphic to $\rho_2$ in the sense that is stated in the accepted answer of this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108306/being-isomorphic-as-representations-of-a-group-g). I guess, the former  case is not meant here since I could not find anything interesting concerning representations that are isomorphic maps. However, there might also be the possibility that these were typos and the author meant to state:

(1) If $V_1$ and $V_2$ are not isomorphic, we have $f=0$.

That is the statement from the [Wiki page of Schur's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_lemma). 
Does anyone know what is meant here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On p. 4, Serre defines what it means for two representations to be *isomorphic:*

> Let $\rho$ and $\rho'$ be two representations of the same group $G$ in vector spaces $V$ and $V'$. These representations are said to be *similar* (or **isomorphic**) if there exists a linear isomorphism $\tau\colon V\to V'$ which "transforms" $\rho$ into $\rho'$, that is, which satisfies the identity $$ \tau\circ\rho(s) = \rho'(s)\circ \tau\quad\text{for all $s\in G$.}$$

The map $\tau$ is then said to be an **isomorphism** of the representations $\rho,\rho'$. So what (1) means more explicitly is "if $f$ is not an isomorphism of the representations $\rho_1,\rho_2$, we have $f = 0$."

Comment: That's not what (1) means. (1) says, exactly, "if *there does not exist* an isomorphism between $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$, then $f = 0$." The statement you write is also true but very slightly stronger.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Yes, thank you for pointing this out. I wanted to draw attention to this. Originally I thought of simply citing the definition Serre gives, and saying that the best way to understand (1) would be take the contrapositive, but ultimately I think given that we have introduced $f$, it would be clearest and most useful to frame it this way.